# When were dilithium crystals first mentioned in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

I would like to know the very first episode in which dilithium crystals were mentioned/seen.

As I understand it, they were called lithium crystals in *Where No Man Has Gone Before* and *Mudd's Women*, but after that they were always dilithium.

Answer (score 8):

Out of universe, the first mention of dilithium crystals was in the TOS episode "[The Alternative Factor](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/20.htm)" (season 1, episode 20):

> **UHURA:** *Nothing yet, sir.*
>
> **MASTERS:** (A woman in a blue uniform) ***Report on the dilithium crystals,** Captain.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Yes.*
>
> **MASTERS:** *Whatever that phenomenon was, it drained almost all of our crystals completely. It could mean trouble.*

Those two very early references to "*lithium* crystals" have never been completely explained as far as I know. But there are (in-universe) earlier mentions of dilithium being used as an energy source, for instance in Enterprise - "[Cold Front](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/11.htm)" (which takes place about 110 years before TOS):

> **SONSORRA:** *I'm a warp field theorist.*
>
> **TUCKER:** *Oh. Well, I guess that covers the basics. Any questions?*
>
> **ALIEN:** ***How do you regulate positron flow in your dilithium matrix?***
>
> **TUCKER:** *Good one. I'll bring up the schematic of the reactor assembly and you can see for yourself*.

Comment: It's the correct episode, but it's actually episode 27, not 20